# Embedding kibana dashboard in external ui prompts login

Tags: iframe, elastic-stack, kibana-7

I am running Kibana 7.7.1 on windows.
I am using share option shown at the top of Kibana dashboard to share dashboard by using iframe core in web app but it is asking for login. I found that removing login prompt can be done by 2 ways

1. Making POST request to api/security/v1/login with username and password in the request body which returns cookie containing "sid" setting that to the browser solves the problem.
2. Using reverse proxy mechanism using nginx with header of basic authorization.

I have been trying 1st option but everytime I send a request to the endpoint I get { "statusCode":404,""error":"Not Found","message":"Not Found"}

Even, I am not able to find this endpoint anywhere in Kibana documentation.

Any idea what might be the cause?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer to this question can be found on the link
https://discuss.elastic.co/t/using-authentication-api-of-kibana-api-security-v1-login-returns-404-not-found/246920